# SignalR Broadcast from Controller not working

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm using the latest version of SignalR (1.0.1).  I am trying to broadcast from my controller to the hub and having a few issues:

1. My client does not seem to be getting messages.
2. It doesn't seem that my hub context even has an 'addMessage' defined:

My hub:

```
public class SignalRPriceHub : Hub
{
    public void sndMessage(string msg)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(msg + "****");
    }
}
```

Javascript client:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
.....
var myHub = $.connection.signalRPriceHub;
myHub.client.addMessage = function (message) {
    alert(message);
};
```

Controller:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SignalRPriceHub>();
context.Clients.All.addMessage("TestOutsideMessage!!!");
```

A few things I noticed:
1. My hub context doesn't seem to have an 'addMessage'
{"'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.ClientProxy' does not contain a definition for 'addMessage'"}  System.Exception {Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException}

1. If I run the following code from the same file as my client code above, I do get a message.

   var myHub = $.connection.signalRPriceHub;
   $.connection.hub.start(function () {
       myHub.server.sndMessage("Hello World!");
   });

Can anyone shed some light as to what might be happening?  Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll go over the faults in your initial application which shed light to why your second bullet point makes it all work.

In your javascript client you must start the connection:

```
$.connection.hub.start();
```

You must then request the message on your hub by calling the sndMessage command:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
    myHub.server.sndMessage("Hello world");
});
```

The reason why you do not see an addMessage function on your hub context is because the hub context .Clients.All is dynamic.

One last note, in order to make the sample work you also need to make sure that in your Application_Start you have RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); .  I assume you already have this since once you add the connection start that everything works.

Comment: Thank you so much for that great detailed answer.  Was "going through the motions" setting this all up without really thinking about what each line of code does.  Thank you again!